# Going from Google Apps for Business to a personal account

Tags: google-workspace

Is it possible to go from a Google Apps business account to personal one?

Google Apps is confusing since the changes and I think I made a mistake.

I moved my account into a business account and I want to change this back but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: A terrible last-resort option would be to set up a completely separate Apps instance, forward all your mail, delete the original instance and add the original domain name as an alias. But certainly, there has got to be a way to do what you mean sanely, as this is not.

Comment: @ The White Phoenix - I was watching some help videos I think I understand more what is happening. It is other applications I signed up where in personal and now they are supported or something. So deleting my personal account really does not matter and I don't really care about the TOS since I am a one man company right now.

Comment: What I still don't get. If I have Email A(business account) on youtube and then I want to log in with Email B(another business account from my company) can they log in?

Comment: There is a Google Apps Discussion Forum that'd be ideal for this question.

Comment: Google recently added a feature that lets you login to multiple google accounts in the same session. I've found it mostly works fairly well. I think you could use that for your youtube scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to mass-migrate your account, but services can be migrated individually. How painful this is depends on how many services you're using. For example, you can import email and contacts from your apps account into a standard Gmail account. Similarly, you can export your calendars (Settings -> Calendars -> Export Calendars) from your Apps account, then import them from another account.